# How to get all related objects of every object in a queryset, filtered by another model in Sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, filtering, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm learning Flask with Sqlalchemy, and get stuck with this issue.
Assume I have 3 model:

```
class Author(db.Model):
    sex = db.Column(db.String) # Male or female
    zone = db.Column(db.String(1)) # (A or B)

class SellPlan(db.Model):
    is_open = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    has_discount = db.Column(db.Boolean)

class Book(db.Model):
    plan = db.Column(db.SellPlan, db.ForeignKey('SellPlan')) 
    author = db.Column(db.Author, db.ForeignKey('Author'))
```

Every book has foreign keys to Plan and Author.
Now, I want to query all Authors who are male, in zone A. And I also want to prefetch (like prefetch in Django), all books of every author which has PlanSell is open and have discount (`is_open=True`, `has_discount=True`), so I can easily access data later, like `author.books`.
I searched I found that we can use `joinedload()` but I still can not figure out how to filter by PlanSell's fields
Please help me ^^

Comment: can you show what should be the result by some example. If I am not wrong then you want author who is male and have discount and is_open and then take his books.

Comment: yes. I want to get all author (male, and live in zone A) with all their books (the books need to be filtered by sell plan (open, and has discount)

Answer (score 0):

I made changes to your code. You don't need to make a table for SellPlan rather include it in the Book table.

```
class Author(db.Model):
    id =  db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    sex = db.Column(db.String) 
    zone = db.Column(db.String(1))
    books = db.relationship("Book",backref="author")


class Book(db.Model):
    sno =   db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(15))
    is_open = db.Column(db.Boolean)     
    has_discount = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("author.id"))
```

I have added id and sno because primary key is needed for creating table.

Now you will add data like this:

```
p4 = Author(sex="male",zone="A")
b2 = Book(name=flask",is_open=True,has_discount=True,author=p4)
```

accessing the data which you want:

```
b = []
a1 = Author.query.filter_by(sex="male",zone="A").all()
for i in a1:
     a = Book.query.filter_by(is_open=True,has_discount=True,author=i).first()
     b.append(a)
```

a1 has the authors,and b has the books (both are list)

Comment: Thanks, @charchit, but that's not what I want. A sell plan can have multiple books related to it, SellPlan must be a separated table. And I think your implementation has poor performance. But I really appreciate your help ^^

Comment: welcome, then you can read this [blog](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/nested-queries-with-sqlalchemy-orm) maybe it helps